# How to automatically deploy api gateway in AWS codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Currently I am able to deploy a lambda by pushing to github. I also automatically deploy a lambda but only because the api gateway is an event in the lambda yaml file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Identifies paragraphs in documents and links to the law
Resources:
  LambdaParagraphLinker:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: LambdaParagraphLinker.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: ./
      Description: Identifies paragraphs in documents and links to the 
      law
       MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 10      
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /LambdaParagraphLinker
            Method: ANY
```

How can I deploy an api gateway using a swagger file ?

Answer (score 2):

Hands down the best way to do this in codepipeline is by using https://serverless.com/ framework. This replaces every super complicated hack-job and workaround I've previously used. Way less complicated IMO.

Create a codepipeline, link it to src & a codebuild project, set a few permissions, done.

//serverless.yml

```
service: my-api
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: api/v1/message
          method: post
```

//buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      #BUILD
      - sudo apt-get update -y
  build:
    commands:
      - echo $environment
      - serverless package --stage $environment --region us-east-1
      - serverless deploy --stage $environment --region us-east-1
```

Or torture yourself by doing one of the options below...

You can do this in cloudformation from within code pipeline. Export the swagger spec from within the gatewayapi console and place in the cloudformation template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  PlayersAPI:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: MyApi
      Description: API Description
      Body:
       "SWAGGER HERE"
```

Hooking this up to lambda is a little bit cumbersome but I can describe the steps. First create a codepipeline project with source, build, and deploy steps.

- src should be standard from github or codecommit
- build should output a zip file and use buildspec.yml  Something like this...

//buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      #BUILD
      - zip -r lambda.zip . -x *.git*
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*.zip'
    - '**/*.yml'
  discard-paths: no
```

Have the build step export an artifact MyAppBuild (or whatever you want to call it)

The final pipeline step is creating the lambda function in this repo as a standalone function through the console(its reusable):
https://github.com/tkntobfrk/codepipeline-lambda-s3

This lambda function downloads the pipeline artifact/zipped lambda function and updates it using boto.

After these steps you could add another step as a cloudformation deploy step. Connect it to the lambda function that you've just deployed.

If you are dealing with multiple environments you could create lambda functions and gatewayapi cloudformation template for each environment then run them in sequence.

- stage 1: src
- stage 2: build
- stage 3: deploy lambda test, deploy gateway api cloudformation test
- stage 4: validate test
- stage 5: deploy lambda prod, deploy gateway api cloudformation prod

Using straight AWS serverless like this works too.  However, you need to use a standard artifact location for the uri's.  The DefinitionUri: for the API can be the exported swagger from the gatewayapi console.

//cloudformation.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  MySimpleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      CodeUri: s3://somebucket/somezip.zip
  MyAPI:
     Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
     Properties:
        StageName: prod
        DefinitionUri: s3://somebucket/somezip.zip
```

Comment: Dear Bruce. Thanks. For the moment I gave up. I ran out of time. I find the Amazon solution extremely complex to get up and running. I do not understand why Amazon does not provide a plug and play solution :-)

Comment: I did go through and validate this works, but it's a fairly complex solution. The real issue is with the Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function' types in cloudformation is they require an external s3 uri.  If you were able to specify the local input artifact in the templates it would be super straightforward and easy within codepipeline.

Comment: Thanks again. Just to mention... My colleague got continuous deployment working on Azure in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

`AWS::Serverless::Api`

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessapi

You can find Swagger docs all over the place, and docs on API Gateway extensions are in the developer guide. I would start by going into the API Gateway console and look at the API that Lambda creates for you. You can go to the 'Stages' page and for any stage, you can Export the API as Swagger.